# What method to use for differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having doubts as to what method to use in the following ODE:

$$2t+3x+(x+2)x'=0$$
As this can be changed into: 
$$x'=\frac{-2t-3x}{x+2}$$

I'm thinking it can be solved by using homogeneous equations method, but I'm not sure this applies because for the $x+2$ in the denominator I'm not sure it would be a homogeneous equation (grade 0 and all).

What would you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get this equation? Was this from a standard undergrad DE textbook (or course)?

Comment: @LordVader007 As an assignment from a teacher. I'm not familiar with American grade designations, but I'm fairly certain my DE course corresponds to undergraduate level (the one you take after high school, in college).Why do you ask, do you think something's wrong with it?

Comment: No, just curious, that's all.

Comment: Ok, so it looks to be of the form of a particular differential equation called "D'alembert Equation". See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/d%27Alembert

Comment: Write it in the form $x=\frac{-t}{x'+3}-\frac{x'}{3+x'}$ and then call $f(x')=\frac{-1}{3+x'}$ and $g(x')=\frac{-x'}{3+x'}$. Differentiate both sides of the equation and transform it of the type $\frac{dt}{dx'}=...$. According to the formulation, it should be then converted to a linear equation.

Comment: FYI-Wolfram spits out a very unpleasant solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27+%3D+%28-2t-3x%29%2F%28x%2B2%29

Comment: OK for D'Alembert, but not only. It is much simpler to transform the ODE into an homogeneous ODE, then a separable ODE just with simple linear change of variables. This doesn't require an high level of knowledge. After that,  the students might find a bit more difficult the integral at the end. Don't be afraid by the solution from WolframAlpha which is over-complicated by the full writing without using intermediate terms.

Comment: @JJacquelin Nice! I just looked at your solution. I'll keep that in mind for next time I get to teach anything about differential equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get 4 solutions when solving it as d'Alembert. 2 of them are singular solutions.

Maple gives one solution though. But the 4 solutions are verified OK by Maple.

Solve 
\begin{align*}
          2\,t+3\,x \left( t \right) + \left( x \left( t \right) +2 \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) &=0
\end{align*}

This is d'Alembert ODE. It has the form 
$x \left( t \right) =t g(x'(t)) + f(x'(t))$. where
$g$ and $f$ are functions of  $x'(t)$.

Solving for $x \left( t \right) $ from the above and keeping only real solutions 
for $x \left( t \right) $ and letting $p=x'(t)$ gives
\begin{align*}
    x \left( t \right)  &= -2\,{\frac {t+p}{3+p}} \tag{1} \\ 
\end{align*}

ODE (1) is now solved.

In this ODE $g(x'(t)) = -2\, \left( 3+p \right) ^{-1}$ and $f(x'(t))=-2\,{\frac {p}{3+p}}$. 
Taking derivatives of (1) w.r.t. $t$ and remembering that $p$ is a function of $t$
results in
\begin{align*}
p &= -2\, \left( 3+p \right) ^{-1}+t\left(2\, \left( 3+p \right) ^{-2}\right) \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}- \left(2\, \left( 3+p \right) ^{-1}-2\,{\frac {p}{ \left( 3+p \right) ^{2}}}\right) \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}\\ 
              p+2\, \left( 3+p \right) ^{-1} &= \left(2\,{\frac {t}{ \left( 3+p \right) ^{2}}}-2\, \left( 3+p \right) ^{-1}+2\,{\frac {p}{ \left( 3+p \right) ^{2}}}\right) \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}\tag{2}\\ 
\end{align*}

The singular solution is found by setting $ \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}=0$, which implies that 
           $p$ is a constant. From the above, this results in
           \begin{align*}
        p+2\, \left( 3+p \right) ^{-1}&=0\\ 
\end{align*}
Solving the above for $p$ gives
\begin{align*}
p&=-1\\ 
p&=-2\\ 
\end{align*}
Substituting $-1$ values in (1) gives the singular solution 
$$
x \left( t \right) =-t+1
$$
Substituting $-2$ values in (1) gives the singular solution 
$$
 x \left( t \right) =-2\,t+4
$$

The general solution is  found when $ \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}\neq 0$. Rewriting (2) as
\begin{align*}
\frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} &={\frac {{p}^{3}+6\,{p}^{2}+11\,p+6}{2\,t-6}}\\ 
\end{align*}

Inverting the above gives
\begin{align*}
       \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}p}} &={\frac {2\,t-6}{{p}^{3}+6\,{p}^{2}+11\,p+6}}\\ 
       \frac{  \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}-\left(2\,{\frac {t}{{p}^{3}+6\,{p}^{2}+11\,p+6}}\right) &= -6\, \left( {p}^{3}+6\,{p}^{2}+11\,p+6 \right) ^{-1}\\ 
\end{align*}

$t \left( p \right) $ is now the dependent variable and $p$ as the independent variable. 
Now this ODE is solved for $t \left( p \right) $.

\begin{align*}
t' &= F(p,t)\\ 
 &=-6\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+3\,p+2 \right) }}+2\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+3\,p+2 \right) }} t\\ 
\end{align*}

Writing the ODE as
\begin{align*} 
t' -2\,{\frac {t}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+3\,p+2 \right) }} &= -6\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+3\,p+2 \right) }}
\end{align*}
Then the integrating factor $\mu$ is
$$
\mu = e^{\int -2\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+3\,p+2 \right) }}\mathop{\mathrm{d}p}} = {{\rm e}^{2\,\ln  \left( p+2 \right) -\ln  \left( 3+p \right) -\ln  \left( p+1 \right) }}
$$

Which can be simplified to 
$$
       \mu ={\frac { \left( p+2 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( p+1 \right) }}
$$
The ode becomes
\begin{align*}
           \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{ \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}}\left( \mu t\right) &= \mu \left(-6\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+3\,p+2 \right) }}\right) \\ 
           \frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{ \mathop{\mathrm{d}p}} \left({\frac {t \left( p+2 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( p+1 \right) }}\right) &= \left({\frac { \left( p+2 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( p+1 \right) }}\right) \left(-6\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( {p}^{2}+3\,p+2 \right) }}\right)\\ 
            \mathrm{d} \left({\frac {t \left( p+2 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( p+1 \right) }}\right)  &= {\frac {-6\,p-12}{ \left( p+1 \right) ^{2} \left( 3+p \right) ^{2}}}\,\mathrm{d} p
\end{align*}
Integrating gives
\begin{align*}
         {\frac {t \left( p+2 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( p+1 \right) }} &= {\frac {3}{2\,p+2}}-{\frac {3}{6+2\,p}} + C_1
\end{align*}
Dividing both sides by the integrating factor $\mu={\frac { \left( p+2 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 3+p \right)  \left( p+1 \right) }}$ results in

$$
          t(p) = {\frac { \left( 3+p \right)  \left( p+1 \right) }{ \left( p+2 \right) ^{2}} \left( {\frac {3}{2\,p+2}}-{\frac {3}{6+2\,p}} \right) }+{\frac {C_{{1}} \left( 3+p \right)  \left( p+1 \right) }{ \left( p+2 \right) ^{2}}}
$$

Simplifying the above gives
$$
          t(p) = {\frac {3+ \left( {p}^{2}+4\,p+3 \right) C_{{1}}}{ \left( p+2 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
Solving for $p$ from the above in terms of $t$ gives
\begin{align*}
 p_{1} &= {\frac {1}{t-C_{{1}}} \left( -2\,t+2\,C_{{1}}+\sqrt {-tC_{{1}}+{C_{{1}}}^{2}+3\,t-3\,C_{{1}}} \right) }\\ 
 p_{2} &= -{\frac {1}{t-C_{{1}}} \left( 2\,t-2\,C_{{1}}+\sqrt {-tC_{{1}}+{C_{{1}}}^{2}+3\,t-3\,C_{{1}}} \right) }\\ 
\end{align*}

Substituting each one of the above solution for $p$ in (1) gives 
the general solutions.

Substituting $p_{1}$ back into Eq. (1) gives
$$
              x \left( t \right) =-2\,{t \left( 3+{\frac {-2\,t+2\,C_{{1}}+\sqrt {-tC_{{1}}+{C_{{1}}}^{2}+3\,t-3\,C_{{1}}}}{t-C_{{1}}}} \right) ^{-1}}-2\,{\frac {-2\,t+2\,C_{{1}}+\sqrt {-tC_{{1}}+{C_{{1}}}^{2}+3\,t-3\,C_{{1}}}}{t-C_{{1}}} \left( 3+{\frac {-2\,t+2\,C_{{1}}+\sqrt {-tC_{{1}}+{C_{{1}}}^{2}+3\,t-3\,C_{{1}}}}{t-C_{{1}}}} \right) ^{-1}}
$$
Which simplifies to 
$$
x \left( t \right) ={1 \left( -2\,\sqrt {- \left( C_{{1}}-3 \right)  \left( t-C_{{1}} \right) }-2\,{t}^{2}+ \left( 2\,C_{{1}}+4 \right) t-4\,C_{{1}} \right)  \left( t-C_{{1}}+\sqrt {- \left( C_{{1}}-3 \right)  \left( t-C_{{1}} \right) } \right) ^{-1}}
$$
Substituting $p_{2}$ back into Eq. (1) gives
$$
x \left( t \right) =-2\,{t \left( 3-{\frac {2\,t-2\,C_{{1}}+\sqrt {-tC_{{1}}+{C_{{1}}}^{2}+3\,t-3\,C_{{1}}}}{t-C_{{1}}}} \right) ^{-1}}+2\,{\frac {2\,t-2\,C_{{1}}+\sqrt {-tC_{{1}}+{C_{{1}}}^{2}+3\,t-3\,C_{{1}}}}{t-C_{{1}}} \left( 3-{\frac {2\,t-2\,C_{{1}}+\sqrt {-tC_{{1}}+{C_{{1}}}^{2}+3\,t-3\,C_{{1}}}}{t-C_{{1}}}} \right) ^{-1}}
$$
Which simplifies to 
$$
x \left( t \right) ={1 \left( 2\,{t}^{2}-2\,tC_{{1}}-4\,t+4\,C_{{1}}-2\,\sqrt {- \left( C_{{1}}-3 \right)  \left( t-C_{{1}} \right) } \right)  \left( -t+C_{{1}}+\sqrt {- \left( C_{{1}}-3 \right)  \left( t-C_{{1}} \right) } \right) ^{-1}}
$$

Verification of solutions using Maple

\begin{equation*}
\boxed{x \left( t \right) =-t+1}
\end{equation*}

Verified OK

\begin{equation*}
\boxed{x \left( t \right) =-2\,t+4}
\end{equation*}

Verified OK

\begin{equation*}
\boxed{x \left( t \right)  = \frac { -2\,\sqrt {- \left( C_{{1}}-3 \right)  \left( t-C_{{1}} \right) }-2\,{t}^{2}+ \left( 2\,C_{{1}}+4 \right) t-4\,C_{{1}} }{ t-C_{{1}}+\sqrt {- \left( C_{{1}}-3 \right)  \left( t-C_{{1}} \right) } }}
\end{equation*}

Verified OK

\begin{equation*}
\boxed{x \left( t \right)  = \frac { 2\,{t}^{2}-2\,tC_{{1}}-4\,t+4\,C_{{1}}-2\,\sqrt {- \left( C_{{1}}-3 \right)  \left( t-C_{{1}} \right) } }{ -t+C_{{1}}+\sqrt {- \left( C_{{1}}-3 \right)  \left( t-C_{{1}} \right) } }}
\end{equation*}

Verified OK

Solution by Maple to compare with is 
\begin{align*}
x \left( t \right) &=-2-{\frac {1}{2\,{\it \_C1}} \left( 4\, \left( -3+t \right) {\it \_C1}+1+\sqrt {4\, \left( -3+t \right) {\it \_C1}+1} \right) }\\ 
\end{align*}

For reference: The commands to solve the ODE in Mathematica and Maple are

```
DSolve[2*t+3*x[t]+(x[x]+2)*x'[t]==0,x[t],t]                  
dsolve(2*t+3*x(t)+(x(t)+2)*diff(x(t),t)=0,x(t),singsol=all)
```

The strange thing is that Maple does not say this is d'Alembert. Only  that it is either `homogeneous, class C` or `_Abel, 2nd type, class A` or `rational`. Not sure now why it does not mention the type d'Alembert.

Comment: Thank you! I think d'Alembert is out of scope for my current course, so I'm thinking the teacher might have be a mistake here. I will discuss it with her shortly, thanks again!

Comment: A quick question, how do you tell Maple to show step by step solution? dsolve only gives me the final solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

$$2t+3x+(x+2)\frac{dx}{dt}=0$$
By inspection one see that : $\quad 2t+3x=2(t-3)+3(x+2)$
$$2(t-3)+3(x+2)+(x+2)\frac{dx}{dt}=0$$

This draw us to the change of variables : $\quad\begin{cases}
X=x+2 \\
T=t-3
\end{cases}\quad$ thus $\quad \frac{dX}{dT}= \frac{dx}{dt}$.
$$2T+3X+X\frac{dX}{dT}=0\quad\implies\quad \frac{dX}{dT}=-\frac{2T+3X}{X}$$
This is an homogeneous ODE. The usual change of function is :
$$X(T)=T\:F(T)$$
$X'=F+TF'=-\frac{2T+3TF}{TF}$
$$T\frac{dF}{dT}=-\frac{(F+1)(F+2)}{F}$$
This ODE is separable. Solving (easy, but rather boring) is for you.

Comment: This seem simpler. I'll give it a go when I get home, perhaps this is what my teacher intended. Just a  question I don't follow your substitution of $X=x+2$, $T=t-3$, why did you choose those values? Also $2T=2(t-3)=2t-6, where did the -6 come from? Thanks!

Comment: See my answer. The intermediate steps for the change of variables are added.

Answer (score 1):

Compressing the d'Alembert treatment: Insert $p=x'$, then 
$$
2t+3x+(x+2)p=0.
$$
If $p$ is constant, then the $t$ derivative of this equation gives
$$
2+3p+p^2=0\implies p=-1\text{  or  } p=-2.
$$
In the other cases, locally use $p$ as parameter and use $T(p)$, $X(p)$ as the dependent functions. Then from the chain rule $X'(p)=pT'(p)$ and from the equation
$$
0=2T'+3X'+(X+2)+pX'\implies 0=(2+3p+p^2)X'+p(X+2)
$$
which is separable
$$
\frac{X'}{X+2}=\frac{p}{(p+1)(p+2)}=\frac{2}{p+2}-\frac1{p+1}
\implies
X+2=\frac{C(p+2)^2}{p+1}
$$
Inserting this back into the original equation gives a parametrization of the solution curves with
$$
2T=6-\frac{C(p+3)(p+2)^2}{p+1}.
$$